# jqplot Pie Chart data label format precision without trailing zeros

Tags: jquery, formatting, jqplot, printf, pie-chart

I would like to know how to **format** the data labels on a **Pie Chart** so it shows **max 2 decimal** characters, and **never** shows **trailing zeros**, for example:

```
2 -> 2
2.0 -> 2
2.566 -> 2.57
```

In other words, I am asking **how to set `dataLabelFormatString` parameter**?
I know it is using `sprintf`, thus I tried '%.2f' and '%g'. They do not solved my problem though. Since the first makes each number to show to decimal characters, the other just removes trailing zeros but doesn't work with precision as in this case the digits you place in front of it ,e.g. '%.2g' refer to the total length of the character.

I do not know how to, effectively, combine these two (is it even possible?). How to set the parameter, for example, to first format using '%.2f' then using '%g' and it should do the trick, but how to do it?

Can I maybe 'inject' an if/else into the format, if so then how?

Otherwise the only way I can think of would be to, once the plot is drawn, run a jquery script getting the labels and applying `parseFloat(label.toFixed(2))` on each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close this topic I am posting my answer here. I managed to solved this issue, thanks to `jQuery`. Once again it appears to be a real life saver when it comes to doing the client side. :)

I have approached it similarly to my thought mentioned in my question, i.e. using `parseFloat(label.toFixed(2))`. Though I did it in a slightly inverted way. I decided to set the chart to use `label` for `dataLabels` parameter. I use the `$.jqplot.postDrawHooks.push(...)` to bind my function for execution once the chart is finished painting. My function modifies the legend labels to display names instead of percentage values which I calculate before I set them to data array.

This approach works perfectly as I would want it. [To those interested, please find my jsfiddle showing the solution here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/NYewy/)

If someone has a better solution **I am very keen to move the accept from my answer at any time**.

Comment: I needed to format the labels on the pie chart and it worked better for me if it is '%.2f%'

Comment: @Teddy thanks. In my case I really needed to remove the trailing zeros thus the format you mention was not for me as it always will have 2 digits after the dot. In my case I had a lot of data on the chart and I wanted to have the labels but at the same time to avoid the unnecessary clutter from zeros which doesn't tell anything :)