# Using php, ajax and jqplot to make a pie chart

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jqplot

I am attempting to make a pie chart using a php file that gets the information from MySQL, JSON encodes it, and then sends it to my JS file to make the pie chart. I have looked at most of the other questions posted here and none of them help me at all. I have attempted to re-qrite my code to match ones that seem to fit, but nothing is working.
My php file is:

```
$shelvDate = $_POST['shelvDate'];
$x = 0;

// get information from database for shelving chart
$shelv = $conn -> query ("SELECT sum(quantity) as qty, date_process, created_by, first_name from inventory LEFT JOIN users on users.user_id =inventory.created_by
    WHERE date_process = '$shelvDate' GROUP BY created_by" );
$num_rows = $shelv->num_rows;

if($num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $shelv->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row['qty'] > 0){
            $qtyArray[$x] = $row['qty'];
            $nameArray[$x] = $row['first_name'];
        }
        $x++;

        $pairs = array('first_name' => $nameArray, 'qty' => $qtyArray);
    } // end of while statement
} //end of if statement

$conn->close();
echo json_encode(array($pairs));
```

When I attempt to get the data into my `ajax/js` I get an error. My `JS` is:

```
$("#getRecords").live('click', function() {
    var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
        var ret = null;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: url,
            dataType:"json",
            data: ({shelvDate: $('#shelvDate').val()}),
            success: function(data) {
                for(var x=0; x<data.first_name.length; x++) {
                    var info = [data.first_name[x], data.qty[x]];
                    ret.push(info);
                }
        }); // end of ajax call

        return ret;
    }; // end of ajaxDataRenerer call

    // The url for our json data
    var jsonurl = "shelvChart.php";
    var plot2 = $.jqplot('shelvChart', jsonurl,{
    seriesDefaults: {
           // Make this a pie chart.
           renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
           rendererOptions: {
               // Put data labels on the pie slices.
               // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
               showDataLabels: true
           }
        }, 
        title: "Books Shelved",
        dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
        dataRendererOptions: {
            unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
        }
    });
});
```

I am don't know what I'm doing wrong or even where to go from here as I am still new to AJAX and JS. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Jim

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(data);` inside of `success: function(data) {}`

Comment: if I add in an alert box in the success:function(data), I get name[object,object],qty[object,object].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It would be very useful to see a real `JSON` string you are getting, cause I am not sure how you can get `name[object,object],qty[object,object]` after calling `alert(ret)` or maybe you are referring to other alert?.*

Anyway from what you are saying your problem is that you must make sure that the array returned by the `ajaxDataRenderer` function is of a proper format that is accepted by a pie chart.

Therefore, for example, inside your `PHP` or `JavaScript` code you need to make sure that the returned array `ret` is of the following format:

```
ret = [[name[0], qty[0]], [name[1], qty[1]], ...];
```

This way all values that are in name array will be used as labels and qty array will be used as values from which the percentage will be evaluated.

[Similar approach that shows how to prepare data for a chart is shown in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10329792/613495)

Comment: After doing some debugging, I was able to get some actual data out of my mysql query.  Now in the alert(ret) I get:  first_name,Mike,Cory,Doug,Pond,Santos,qty,471,80,101,59,46.  I though json was supposed to format this info in [ ] form.  I will look at your example now and see if it makes any sense to  me.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I used your code example parts of your code example and now get my alert formatted as : mike,471, cory,80 etc.. but I still do not get it plotted on my chart.  any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle that shows your problem. I am not really sure what is the problem there without seeing the actual code. Also my suggestion was to have arrays of consisting of a [name, qty] pair in `ret` array.

Comment: I was able to get the ret array as [name, qty], now I just can't get the information to show on my chart.  I will attempt to get it in jsfiddle now.  Thanks

Comment: The example code you provided is not runnable, therefore, I cannot see what your problem is. Please, copy and past the **exact** output you are getting when you call `console.log(ret)` or `alert(ret)` after a call to `ajaxDataRenderer` or the result of what you do in your code `alert(JSON.stringify(ret));`. Try just calling the method and outputting the returned value.

Comment: [["Mike", "471"], ["Cory", "80"], ["Doug", "101"], ["Pond", "59"], ["Santos", "46"]] is the result of console.log(ret) after calling ajaxDataRenderer.  Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: At the first look the problem is that you are giving Strings as the second element in each arrays and the plot expects values. This jsfiddle shows a pie chart done for your data with consideration that the 2nd element is not a String http://jsfiddle.net/v8Kkh/3/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11654/discussion-between-jim-and-boro)